# How to remove image from uiimageview op uibutton

Tags: iphone, ios

I initialize `UIImageVIew` with placeholder.png image. When I try to change placeholder.png with an image from `UIImagePicker` controller, it not changing.

```
employeePhoto=[[UIImageView alloc] init];
[employeePhoto setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 150, 150)];
[employeePhoto setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
[self.view addSubview:employeePhoto];
```

In `UIImagePickerController` delegate

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *image=[info valueForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

    [employeePhoto setImage:nil]; // or employeePhoto.image=nil;
    [employeePhoto setImage:image];

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

But after dismissing the picker `UIImageView` does't change. also I tried with `UIButton` instead of `UIImageView`. `UIImageView` and `UIButton` declare as `@property(nonatomic, retain)` and I'm using xcode 4.6.1.

Please help me to solve this problem...

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: Did you try to set a break point near UIImage *image to see whether a image is returned or try NSLog(@"Image: %@",image);.

Comment: [employeePhoto removeFromSuperview]; try to use this instead of [employeePhoto setImage:nil];

Comment: Is `employeePhoto` save in an instance variable? You create it in the first snippet but it's not clear what you do with it.

Comment: If the image is not changing, there are 2 possiblities 1. didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method is not called or 2. employeePhoto is nil.

Comment: why you are setting image after setting the image to nil? Just try removing it

Answer (score 1):

please try following code :

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIImageView *employeePhoto;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIImagePickerController *imagePicker;


/* Alloc and Init UIImageView and AddSubview to UIView */

self.employeePhoto = [[UIImageView alloc] init] autorelease];
[self.employeePhoto setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 150, 150)];
[self.employeePhoto setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
[self.view addSubview:self.employeePhoto];

 /* Alloc and Init UIImagePickerController in ViewDidLoad */ 

 self.imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] autorelease];
 self.imagePicker.delegate = self;
 self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
 self.imagePicker.mediaTypes =[UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:self.imagePicker.sourceType];
 [self presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];

/* Write UIImagePickerController Delegate Method */ 

- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *original = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    self.employeePhoto.image = original;
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Please try this code and let me know if you are facing any problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) picker
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info
{
    UIImage*image = [info valueForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [employeePhoto setImage: image];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES 
                                   completion: NULL];
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
UIImage *image=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
```

instead of

```
UIImage *image=[info valueForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
```

and alloc employeePhoto in viewDidLoad

Comment: i tried with your suggestion but it's not working. When i initialize uiimageview with out placeholder.png image then it's working fine. Thanks for comment

Comment: have you set delegate of UIImagePickerController

Comment: yes.... i tried with different options. when i commended on this line //[employeePhoto setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]]; then it's working fine..

Answer (score 0):

if you had done

```
piker.allowsImageEditing = NO;
```

then

```
UIImage *image=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
```

if you had done

```
piker.allowsImageEditing = YES;
```

then use

```
UIImage *image=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
```

mabe it will help you. but first check you'll get image or not in didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo.

Comment: i tried with different options. when i commended on this line //[employeePhoto setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]]; then it's working fine..

Comment: then try to change the name of the placeholder.png to any other name.

Answer (score 0):

Use `-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker...` method, after making your imageview = nil.

Again alloc imageview like below...

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage     *image=[info valueForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

    [employeePhoto setImage:nil]; // or employeePhoto.image=nil;
    employeePhoto=[[UIImageView alloc] init];
    [employeePhoto setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 150, 150)];
    [employeePhoto setImage:image];

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

let me know it is working or not!!

Happy Coding!!!